# Mount .img disk image using Disks utility in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount, password, interface, disk-image, disk-utility

Simple question, probably naive.

I have a .img file (with password) that I want to “attach and mount” in Ubuntu 22.04, then explore through the graphical interface. (Read-only will be enough.)

Using the standard Disks utility (menu “Attach disk image…”), the password is accepted and the .img file seems mounted (as I can also eject it using Disks utility).

However, when the .img is mounted, there is no window popping up to allow exploration.

How can I open that window ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the very same "Disks" utility (aka "gnome-disk-utility") to create .img disk partition images and I only just found out today that the same program can actually mount them as you say.

The trick is that they are not automatically mounted once you attach a .img image—you have to click the ▶ icon to mount it.

*Then* it might not even automatically show a window as you describe, so the easiest thing to do is to just click the link that should now appear in Disks next to "Mounted at [location]".

Alternatively, you can open your file explorer (GNOME Files／Nautilus, Dolphin, Thunar, Caja, Nemo, etc etc) and your mounted disk image should be listed in the left sidebar, at which point you can click it and browse its contents like any other physical disk.

Once you're done, you can eject the mounted image by clicking the icon that looks like — which is located immediately to the right of the ⋮ icon (not to me confused with the "minimize window" icon that looks like _ on some desktop environments)